# How to change RAILS default timestamp format for created_at field (to store in DB)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I see a lot of similar questions, but they all tend to focus on the view part instead of the database part. Let's say your customer needs to save the created_at field in a particular local timezone, like EST.

By default rails will save this on the database

> Sun, 13 Oct 2013 20:35:47 +0000

I need to change the behavior so that instead it saves this:

> Sun, 13 Oct 2013 16:35:47 +0000

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the timezone that ActiveRecord will take into account in `config/application.rb`. For example you could add the following:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

From the [official guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record):

> - `config.active_record.default_timezone` determines whether to use
>     Time.local (if set to :local) or Time.utc (if set to :utc) when
>     pulling dates and times from the database. The default is :utc for
>     Rails, although Active Record defaults to :local when used outside of
>     Rails.
> - `config.time_zone` sets the default time zone for the application and
>     enables time zone awareness for Active Record.

Comment: Thanks Agis. I might have something else wrong. After I added the two lines in your answer to my application.rb file, Rails populated the created_at field with localtime - 4 hours. So if i added a record at 6pm EST it will record the record created_at as 2pm. Also, with the two lines of code in your answer my default show all records view stopped showing the created_at field, it shows like it was blank now.